# Facebook Share Javascript SDK Callback yields undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

I am trying to detect if a user on my site successfully shares content onto their facebook page. I am following the documentation of the facebook sdk and a few tutorials and came up with this

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <button class='share-btn'>click</button>
    <script>
        function fb_share() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'snip',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.8'
            });
            FB.ui( {
                method: 'share',
                name: "Facebook API: Tracking Shares using the JavaScript SDK",
                href: "https://test.com",
                picture: "http://test.com",
                caption: "Tracking Facebook Shares on your website or application is a useful way of seeing how popular your articles are with your readers. In order to tracking Shares, you must used the Facebook JavaScript SDK."
            }, function( response ) {
                if ( response !== null) {
                    console.log( response );
                    // ajax call to save response


                }
            } );


        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.share-btn').on( 'click', fb_share );
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

when I see the response in the console...it simply says `undefined`.

Can anyone tell me how they accomplished this?

Comment: seems like undefined is the default response if the post does not go through.... so technically the sdk is working properly?

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user shared?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response // And be aware, rewarding users for sharing or gating content behind it in any way is not allowed. If you are not sure what you can and can not do, start with https://developers.facebook.com/policy